# Create a stored procedure with if beetween queries MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am looking to convert this query from SQL Server to Mysql:

```
create procedure Valor
    @valor int
as 
begin
    if @valor = 1
    begin
        select 1
    end
    else
    begin
        select 2
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As its a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Valor (valor int)
returns int DETERMINISTIC
return if(valor=1,1,2);
```

Comment: This is a valid solution but I was looking to generate queries within the if

Comment: Ask a better question next time and you're likely to get a solution that matches it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what served me.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mysp ()
```

BEGIN
IF @@server_id=2 THEN DROP DATABASE accounting; END IF;
END;